# How to install utils in google co lab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Hi I am working in google co-lab. although i have installed this library utils but every time its giving error
:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from utils import utils # <-----

class SpeechDataGenerator():
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about [Python Utils](https://pypi.org/project/python-utils/) package, then you should import it this way:

```
from python_utils import utils
```

Be sure that module was installed by executing this cell:

```
!pip install python_utils
```

Also it is recommended to restart runtime after module installation.

Comment: Actually i am using google co lab can u plz eloborate. Thanks in adv